# Relacionar campos y subcampos en sugar CRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Tengo un sugarCRM Profesional 8.0, en el que tengo los siguientes modulos:
Cotizaciones, Lineas de cotización, y Lugares, con la siguiente lógica de relación.

- Cada cotización puede tener n lineas
- Cada linea de cotización tiene solamente UN Lugar

Hasta el momento ya tenemos la relación para traer datos de la linea de cotización

```
<?php

if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');


require_once('include/Sugarpdf/sugarpdf/sugarpdf.pdfmanager.php');


    class OpportunitiesSugarpdfPdfmanager extends SugarpdfPdfmanager
    {

        public function preDisplay()
        {
            parent::preDisplay();
            $this->getProducts();  
        }

        protected function getProducts() 
        {
            $this->bean->load_relationship('products');
            if($this->bean->products) {
                $products_list = $this->bean->products->getBeans();
                $map = $products->get_linked_beans('LUG1_Lugares','Lugar');
                $products = array();
                foreach ($products_list as $products) {   
                $mapField = PdfManagerHelper::parseBeanFields($map,true);
                $productFields = PdfManagerHelper::parseBeanFields($products, true);
                    $products[] = $productFields;
                }

                 $this->ss->assign('products', $products);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sin embargo la parte de $map no esta funcionando para traernos la imagen del mapa del modulo Lugar, y usar $products.LUG1_Lugares.mapaevento tampoco funciona.
¿Tienen alguna idea de como se puede traer exclusivamente un campo imágen desde un sub-sub nivel?

Comment: Tienes un typo, deberia ser `parseBeanFields`

Comment: @alanfcm ya corregi el typo de la pregunta